# Походження слова "пляцок"

Tags: етимологія

Цікавить слово *"пляцки" ("пляцок")*.

[image]

Значення в словниках не знайшла, лише в Вікіпедії.

> [Пляцок](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%BA) будь-яка пласка страва, виріб з якого-небудь тіста, тонкий
>   коржик.

Яке походження має слово ***"пляцок"***?

Answer (score 2):

Слово **пляцок** польського походження, що знаходимо в [Етимологічному словнику](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm):
[image]

[image]

Comment: як вам не складно, будьте ласкаві переписати це все текстом або зменшити розмір знімків екрану. дуже складно читати.

Answer (score -1):

[Словник Галицького діалекту](http://www.aratta-ukraine.com/text_ua.php?id=2291) дає таке визначення: «Пляцки (пляцок) — солодкий пиріг або деруни, картопляники».

[На сайті «Модне слівце»](https://uamodna.com/articles/plyacok/) також вказується, що це слово поширене здебільшого на Галичині (також [«Великий тлумачний словник української мови»](https://classes.ru/all-ukrainian/dictionary-ukrainian-explanatory-term-126288.htm) зазначає, що це слово західноукраїнське), але це й не дивно, бо потрапило воно у нашу мову з польської (див. «Placek» у [Польській Вікіпедії](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placek); ще з [«Великої енциклопедії кулінарного мистецтва»](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_pohlebkin/2022) В. В. Похльобкіна російською: «Пляцек. Кондитерское изделие старопольской кухни, польское пирожное, выпекаемое обычно к католическим праздникам, к дням поминовения умерших родственников, отчего эти пирожные часто называют в Польше дзяды»).

Comment: Не бачу причини цитувати рос.мовою.